# printing in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I need help to solve a printing problem completely blocking my project. To be precise and clear, I have two articles Joomla containing PHP code (I use the pluging Free sourcerer).

### The first article contains the following code:

```
{source}
  <form method="post" action="http://localhost/essai/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2">
     <p>
         <input type="text" name="num" />
     </p>
   <input type="submit" value="Display the value of num" />
  </form>
{/source}
```

### The second article whose id is 2 contains the following code:

```
{sourcer}
   if (isset ($_POST [ 'num'])) { 
       $Address=J Request :: getVar( 'num', '', 'post'); 
       echo $Address; 
   } else { 
       echo "num does not exist";
   }
{/source}
```

My objective is recover the value of the input field of the form num in the second article with id 2 and print. When I click on the button "Display the value of num" value zone `num` is retrieved and displayed, but when I click on the link to print
the article, "Does not exist num" is displayed in the open windows.
When I print the article, `$ _POST ['num']` does not exist!

Is that this is a problem printing in Joomla or other? Help me please.

> **NB**: I use  Joomla_2.5.9, Template Beez2 integrated in joomla,
>   Sourcerer-Free v4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 changes you need to make in order to get this to work.

### 1 - I have included the form inside the PHP

```
{source}
<?php       
    echo'<form method="post" action="http://localhost/essai/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2">' .
        '<p>' .
        '<input type="text" name="num" />' .
        '</p>' .
        '<input type="submit" value="Display the value of num" />' .
        '</form>';
?>
{/source}
```

### 2 - Remove some of the extra SPACES from the code

```
{source}
<?php  
   if (isset($_POST['num'])) { 
       $Address=JRequest :: getVar('num','','post'); 
       echo $Address; 
   } else { 
       echo "num does not exist";
   }        
?>
{/source}
```

Comment: The code works fine
The problem is a printing problem. The value of the variable $adress is correctly displayed in Article 2 (id = 2), but when I click on the icon to print this article, the code is interpreted article2 again and displays "num Does not exist ", as if $ _POST ['num'] no longer exists.
I think this is a problem Bezz_20 template, but I really do not know what is the problem.